# How to reference model type from view model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Total javascript noob here...  Have three files: knockout, RoomModel, and RoomViewModel

## RoomModel

```
function RoomModel(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
}
```

## RoomViewModel

```
function RoomViewModel(roomModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(roomModel.Name).toLowerCase();
}
```

How does `RoomViewModel` know what a `RoomModel` is?

I put them all together in the view, but not sure if this is right either...

```
<body>
<script src="Models/RoomModel.js"></script>
<script src="ViewModels/RoomViewModel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js'>
    var roomViewModel = new RoomViewModel(new RoomModel('Hello World'));
    ko.applyBindings(roomViewModel);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a static typing system. Instead, it helps to think of JS as having [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): "if a variable walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck".

In light of your question:

> How does RoomViewModel know what a RoomModel is?

The answer then would be: if the input variable for the `RoomViewModel` constructor function has a `Name` property, it might as well be considered as a valid `RoomModel`.

In other words, the View Model doesn't *need* to know that the input is a valid RoomModel. That's up to the caller. As far as the View Model constructor function, this is equally fine:

```
var roomViewModel = new RoomViewModel({ Name: 'Hello World' });
```

And in some sense: it is.

As a footnote, if you get uneasy by this system, you could look into TypeScript. It adds some more static typing features to JavaScript, allowing you to lock down the type of the input argument to a specific constructor funciton ("class" in Typescript terminology), or to an interface (which allows you to keep some of the duck typing features).

Answer (score 1):

I am trying here to put simplest vesion of MVVM in following steps.

1. Create model. In our case it is roomModel. I have marked it observable just for making it interactive.
2. Create instance of Model i.e. roomModelObject  so creating with new keyword.
3. Creating ViewModel where I have used pureComputed again for just understanding purpose.
4. Finally creating new object of ViewModel and binding it with view through ko.applybinding

Same thing can be achieved in different way as well.

```js
//1. Data Model
var roomModel = function RoomModel(name) {
   var self = this;
   self.firstName = ko.observable(name);
}

//2. Create Instance of Model 
var roomModelObject = new roomModel("O.o"); 

//3. Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    
 
    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return roomModelObject.firstName() + "- Computed";
    }, this);
};

// 4. binding
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value:  roomModelObject.firstName" /></p>

<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

Comment: creating instance of `roomModel` outside viewModel and accessing it inside viewModel function err ! not a great one , tough that's work fine here . #instanceSharing .

Comment: @supercool thanks for sharing. Just trying to make it simple. roomModel instance will not give error just check snippet.

Comment: yes its perfectly fine it wont give any error but i'm pointing at bigger picture . all i'm worried is OP may create instance outside like u pointed in `(2)` which leads to undesired results if app'n grows bigger . its always better to move step 2 inside viewModel make instance vm specific . cheers